# How to pass an expression as list elements for a Mathematica command

Tags: expression-manipulation, expression-construction

I'm trying to build a generic function that will calculate sums on different iterators.
To simplify let consider:

```
Sum[x1 + x2 + x3, {x2, 2}, {x3, 2}];

MySum := Function[ Sum[x1 + x2 + x3, ##]];
(* I can call this function like this *)
MySum[{x2, 2}, {x3, 2}];

(*Now let's try an expression*)
xpr = {{x2, 2}, {x3, 2}};
(*Below still works*)
MySum [xpr[[1]], xpr[[2]] ]

(*How to make it generic for an arbitary number of elements?*)
imax = 2; 
MySum [For[ i = 1, i <= imax, i++, xpr[[i]] ] ]
```

I would like to be able to call the function for 1 or 2 elements of the list generically.

Comment: Your function is only adding up lists starting at 1, so on way to do this is by simply using Plus, Apply, Total, and Range like this `MySum := Function[Plus @@@ (Range /@ ##) // Total]`. Forget x1, x2, x3, etc and just send a list to MySum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any length of the `xpr` list:

```
MySum @@ xpr
```

Call just with the first element of `xpr`:

```
MySum @@ xpr[[{1}]]
```

Call just with the first, third, and fifth element of `xpr`:

```
MySum @@ xpr[[{1,3,5}]]
```